# What's up with the SO logo?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro, logo, hacked

Right now the StackOverflow logo is showing as a squished little caveman figure.  Has somebody hacked the sstatic.net site?  Or is this a regular feature of SO, like Google changing its logo for anniversaries and public holidays?

** edit **

Must have been a temporary glitch - it's gone now.   However, for the doubters out there, here is a screen shot of the sstatic.net url.  It's the best I can do to prove I was not imagining things.

[image]

** edit **

hmmm, smaller than I'd like.  Why is that?

Anyway, I am using Firefox so the cache-bug suggestion might be the right answer.

Comment: I don't see anything. Post a screenshot.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Screenshot with freehand circles or you're lying.

Comment: Your image link isn't correctly formatted

Comment: ChrisF - I uploaded the screenshot to Picasa, but it isn't a straightforward process to get it to render.  The thumbnail is the best I can do.

Comment: StackOverflow: So easy a caveman could do it.

Comment: Thanks to Voyager for resizing the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, then this is a possible cache bug.

Comment: It could only be a cache bug, if this kind of logo existed before. What I doubt.

Comment: For a while the browser on my Pre was putting random chunks of one picture where another one should be, such as putting somebody's gravatar where the site logo should be.  Looks like Firefox has the same bug.

Comment: I've seen this bug before in Firefox, it's reading from the wrong cache location.

Answer (score 6):

You are fooling us, aren't you?

The red circle shows, that the original logo is displayed. You photoshopped this one. Or it is a weird browser bug showing images where they shouldn't be.

[http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/9738/kiddingfool.png http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/9738/kiddingfool.png](http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/9738/kiddingfool.png)

Comment: Seriously, why would I make this stuff up?  I have enough on my plate with my day job and all that.

Comment: @APC: That's what they all say! ;) Maybe Ólafur's comment to his own answer points to the right direction, maybe not.

Comment: Anyway, the thing you've circled is the *favicon* which is picked up from the website.  The caveman PNG comes from the URL which I cut'n'pasted out of the SO page source.  However, please feel free to keep on believing I invented the whole episode.

Comment: @APC: In this case, displaying a pure png, the favicon is a miniature display of the image, like a thumbnail.

Comment: @John Smithers, That's not always the case. If you open the picture you uploaded in another tab, you will see a slice of cheese. Favicon's are set in the header.

Comment: ... Though I agree that it was probably 'Shopped

Comment: Well, this happened to me too. This time it was the redgate logo that showed up. And I'm using IE8.

Answer (score 5):

Just saw your question in the related list on the [How was the iconic StackOverflow emblem born?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122636/)

That's my gravatar, Montecristo, a popular greek comic character.
And it's a rat, not a caveman :)

And yes, that was a cache issue.

Comment: Wow, who needs cave exploring when Meta has so many old tubes to crawl around? :)