# Did the SO favicon just change?

Tags: discussion, favicon

It looks to me as if the SO favicon just changed to some weird red and blue thing with the text "jB". Did anyone else notice this? And what does it stand for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me it looks completely normal, even after hard emptying caches a the like:
[image]

That "red and blue thing with the text jB" sounds a lot like [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/)' favicon:
[image]

Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: Yes, that is the one I'm seeing... how weird.

Comment: Well, emptying the cache helped. But I'm still kinda baffled....

Answer (score 1):

The SO favicon (http://sstatic.net/so/favicon.ico) is the same as it has always been for me. This is the one linked to in the source of the SO pages.

Comment: Yup, that icon is definitely the right one... I wonder why my browser has chosen to display jet brains' icon on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a few months ago.  When [I posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26738/whats-up-with-the-so-logo) I got downvoted, accused of making it up, even using Photoshop to fake the evidence.  So it's a relief to find that somebody else has suffered it.

I have since discovdered the source of my rogue icon - [it was Nick-D's avatar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108130/nick-d).