# How was the iconic Stack Overflow emblem born?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, logo, stack-exchange-history

I didn't see a question about this anywhere so I decided to ask it.

I anticipate an answer like "it best represents the site name," which is all right, but I'm sort of looking for an in-depth look at the creation of the logo from, perhaps, the minds of those who created it.

And while we're at it, I'm curious if it is geometrically awesome. And by that I mean, were there separate shapes and such that determined the curve of the overflowing units in the logo? I'd like to know if simple things like those were employed in the creation of the logo.

I ask because it's so recognizable now, like the yellow arches or white "f." It's important to understand that something's icon is much more important than we know in terms of branding on marketing (the people over at Graphic Design probably agree :P).

Comment: What is this "white f" thing of which you speak? :p

Comment: You can find some attempts at approximating the curve in the answers to [Generate the Stack Overflow logo](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/generate-the-stack-overflow-logo) over on CodeGolf.SE.

Comment: As @Andrew said - white f??

Comment: @Rory He's talking about Facebook, btw. I was just making a bad joke :)

Comment: I understand now. I wouldn't have thought of facebook from that description - shows how their marketing has passed me by :-)

Comment: Me too. Had to think hard for the yellow arches, even.

Comment: I doubt you would question it if you actually saw those symbols. ;)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Back when work on Stack Overflow had just started [Jeff Atwood decided](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/logo-design-contest/) to run [a logo design contest on 99designs](http://99designs.com/logo-design/contests/logo-stackoverflow-6774). He eventually [chose the original Stack Overflow logo seen below](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/logo-design-contest-winner/), [designed by one Peter Borlace](http://pbdesignsolutions.com/project/stack-overflow/). There have been [some minor changes since then](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/).

[image: the winning, current Stack Overflow logo]

Jeff also selected these three as the runners-up.

[image: a runner-up logo]

[image: a runner-up logo]

[image: a runner-up logo]

Comment: hmmm, 104 unpaid designers

Comment: And so is uncovered another chapter of StackOverflow's history. Thanks! I really didn't know any of this. :P

Comment: Wait, the footer says "Stack Exchange Inc"  now. Did they change their name back to Stack Exchange from Stack Overflow?